# How to return a (intro'd) hypothesis back to the goal formula?

Tags: coq

For the proof:

```
Parameter A B : Prop.
Goal A->B.
intro A.
```

I get:

```
 1 subgoals
A : A
______________________________________(1/1)
B
```

How do I return then `A` back to the goal section? To return to:

```
1 subgoals
______________________________________(1/1)
A -> B
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `revert` tactic:

```
revert A.
```

It is exactly the inverse of `intro`, cf. [the reference manual.](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual010.html#hevea_tactic39)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `revert` tactic.

Given Coq's plethora of tactics, each with various corner cases and varying quality of documentation, it's quite common that you won't know which tactic to use.

In such cases, I find it useful to think of your proof as a program (see Curry-Howard Isomorphism) and to ask yourself what term you would have to write to solve your goal. The advantages of this approach is that Coq's term language is easier to learn (because there just aren't that many different kinds of terms) and expressive enough to solve all goals solvable with tactics (sometimes the proofs are more verbose though).

You can use the [`refine`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual010.html#hevea_tactic7) tactic to write your proofs in the term language. The argument of `refine` is a term with holes `_`. `refine` discharges the current goal using the term and generates a subgoal for every hole in the term. Once you know how `refine` works, all you have to do is to come up with a term that does what you want. For example:

- revert a hypothesis `h` with `refine (_ h)`.
- introduce a hypothesis `h` with `refine (fun h => _)`.
- duplicate a hypothesis `h` with `refine ((fun h' => _) h)`.

Note that Coq's tactics tend to do quite a bit of magic behind the scenes. For example, the `revert` tactic is "smarter" than the `refine` above when dealing with dependent variables:

```
Goal forall n:nat, n >= 0.
  intro n; revert n.      (* forall n : nat, n >= 0 *)
Restart.
  intro n; refine (_ n).  (* nat -> n >= 0 *)
Restart.
  intro n'; refine ((_ : forall n, n >= 0) n').   (* forall n : nat, n >= 0 *)
Abort.
```

Comment: Honestly I did not understand the magic of `refine (_ h)`, but it is definitely not the same as `revert h` in the case when h is not just a hypothesis, but a parameter `h: nat`. In this case `revert h` gives `forall h:nat, ...` and `refine (_ h)` gives `nat ->...`, which does not make sense

Comment: Aren't both a function that takes a nat? In the first case the nat is named h. In the second case it is not named (probably because it is not used anywhere in the `...`).